# Dev Express : Compilation Error on running project for the first time.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am using dev express for the first time. I created asp.net mvc project. After the project set up, when I run it for the first time I got an error. 
[image]

Comment: Did u get chance to try the below approach?

Answer (score 0):

This problem I had encountered while compiling, you just need to go to the folder specified in the path in the error i.e. C:\Users\avi\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ... (see the entire path written near Source File), delete all the temporary files under the folder --- Temporary ASP.NET Files
If you get access denied error while deleting them, please close your visual studio and delete them, I hope it will help to resolve this error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But unfortunately Devxpress was creating some problems in my current project. so i completely uninstalled it. Next time I will do as per your instructions if problem arises.